# Find addresses of a buffer

Tags: c, gdb, buffer

I have an exercise in which I need to find the start and end address of a buffer (`buf2`). I don't have permissions to edit the code.

Here is the code:

(the password for the level2 code is fsckmelogic)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) { printf("Fail. More Args...\n"); return 1; }
    else {
        setresuid(geteuid(),geteuid(),geteuid());
        char buf2[4096];
        char buf[16];
        const char password[]="XXXXXXXXXXX";
        strncpy(buf, argv[1], sizeof(buf) - 1);
        if (strcmp(buf,password) != 0) {
            printf("Wrong.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            strcpy(buf2,argv[2]);
            printf("%s",buf2);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, so no changing code however I'm assuming you can compile the code.  Also, going to approach this from a hacker point-of-view (given the web site) and only use tools and techniques that might be available to a hacker.  Finally I am making the assumption that you are working with a Linux box.  So, lets compile the code like thus,

```
     gcc level2.c -o so_test
```

Now we want to find out some starting addresses....so lets use `ltrace` (I'm hope it is installed on the system) and we get:

```
     ltrace ./so_test XXXXXXXXXXX ababaabaabab
    __libc_start_main(0x4006f0, 3, 0x7fff291bddb8, 0x400800 <unfinished ...>
    geteuid()                                                      = 1000
    geteuid()                                                      = 1000
    geteuid()                                                      = 1000
    setresuid(1000, 1000, 1000, -1)                                = 0
    strncpy(0x7fff291bdcb0, "XXXXXXXXXXX", 15)                     = 0x7fff291bdcb0
    strcmp("XXXXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXXX")                            = 0
    strcpy(0x7fff291bcca0, "ababaabaabab")                         = 0x7fff291bcca0
    printf("%s", "ababaabaabab")                                   = 12
```

ok...so what?

1. remember that `strncpy` returns a pointer to the destination string, and from the code 
   we know that the destination is `buf`, thus it's starting address is `0x7fff291bdcb0` (on my machine, your number will be different).
2. the third argument to `strncpy` is the number of characters to copy, which in this case is 15.  From the code, we can see that the third argument of `strncpy` is  `sizeof(buf) - 1` which means that `sizeof(buf)` returns 16.  From this we can deduce that the ending address of `buf` is 0x7fff291bdcb1 + 0x10 or ox7fff291bdcc1
3. we can also learn that the starting address of `buf2` is 0x7fff291bcca0 from the results of the `strcpy` function call.
4. We can learn that the string entered by the user was 12 characters long due to the return value from the `printf` function call.
5. So now what is left is to find out the ending point of buf2.  We can start throwing input at it till it blows up on us.  Hint, if you do not want to type a long string of the same character, you can do the following:

   ```
   ltrace ./so_test XXXXXXXXXXX `perl -e "print 'A' x 1024;"`
   ```

just change the 1024 to how many characters you want to pump into buf2.  On my system, through a bit of trial and error, I've found out that the largest value that I can input is 4151, pushing in 4152 A's result in a segmentation fault (so we know that the maximum size of buf2 is going to be less than this).

6. Only thing left do do is figure out the length of buf2.

Hopefully this give you a start, I don't want to do your entire challenge for you :)

Comment: Thank you! finnaly found the addresses

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify the code, and your assignment is to get the beginning and ending ADDRESS of buf2, then isn't the only thing left is to run it with a debugger, and obtain the address from there??

Answer (score -1):

The Starting Address of Buffer can be viewed using

```
 printf("%p", &buff2);
```

Once you get the starting point of address then find the length of the buffer i.e.

```
len=strlen(buff2);
```

Now add the length in pointer then you get he end address of buff2 i.e.

```
 printf("%p %p", *buff2, *buff2+strlen(buff2));
```

Comment: that would be another problem

Comment: I wouldn't call `strlen()` the "length of the buffer"...it's merely the length of the sequence of non-zero characters at the start of the buffer (of course that might be what he really means).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `printf("%p %p", buf2, buf2+4095);`?

Comment: @WeatherVane if the length of buffer is less then 4095 character then what would be answer i.e. 4095 - used to have maximum length of string

Comment: The length of the buffer is 4096, and also please note the use of `&` and not `*` but even the `&` is not required.

Comment: He is coping the argv[2] to buf2 then how could be length would be 4096. as is supposed to have the maximum user input value 4096 bytes long

Comment: both ways are correct its only the way of writing code